# LWJGL + Swing crashing

Tags: java, swing, crash, lwjgl

I am trying to add a LWJGL display to a JFrame. I added the LWJGL to a canvas. However after I move the complete window or alt-tab out, the window just freezes.

```
private JPanel contentPane;

public guiJGen() {
    setResizable(false);
    setBounds(100, 100, 1200, 800);
    contentPane = new JPanel(null);
    setContentPane(contentPane);

    // Model-Viewer
    JPanel panel_model = new JPanel();
    panel_model.setBounds(0, 0, 771, 761);
    contentPane.add(panel_model);
    panel_model.setLayout(null);

    guiModelCanvas canvas = new guiModelCanvas();
    canvas.setBounds(10, 11, 751, 591);
    canvas.setBackground(Color.blue);
    canvas.requestFocusInWindow();
    canvas.setFocusable(true);
    canvas.setIgnoreRepaint(true);
    panel_model.add(canvas);
    this.setVisible(true);
    try {
        Display.setDisplayMode(new DisplayMode(751,591));
        Display.setParent(canvas);
        Display.create();
    } catch (LWJGLException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I just left the most important code and removed the rest.
Why is it crashing? Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's crashing or freezing? First one is usually for heavy work in UI Thread, second for an uncaught exception.

Comment: @omainegra It's freezing, cant interact with the window and I get no errors. What do you mean with _first_ and _second_?

Comment: I meant freezing or crashing

Comment: @omainegra As I said, it is freezing.

Comment: You are using a heavyweight Component(Canvas) inside a lightweight one(JFrame). This might cause problems.